# Sending java bitmap object to native classes for image processing

Tags: android-ndk

I want to design an image filter app. I've searched a lot but found nothing on how to pass java bitmap to c/c++ and then retrieve at native side and apply a basic image filter and return the result to java again to display it on ImageView. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's unclear exactly what the problem is. The general principles for accessing Java objects from C++ are the same regardless of the object's type. If you're unfamiliar with JNI I suggest you start by reading up on the subject.

Comment: I question the problem in parts. I have an image in imageView. That i have converted it in bitmap object. Now i want to pass this bitmap object to C/C++. If i pass it directly then there is an error  because c/c++ will not recognize Java Bitamp. So what is the procedure to pass and retrieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Check the NDK Bitmap plasma sample, it shows how to do exactly that.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/bitmap-plasma

Comment: Ok but anything else a bit easier than this

Comment: It doesn't get much easier than this if you want to use the NDK.

The only alternative would be to use Renderscript, which quite frankly isn't much easier anyway

https://medium.com/@qhutch/android-simple-and-fast-image-processing-with-renderscript-2fa8316273e1

Unless of course, you would be happy to use the predefined filters instead.

https://blog.jayway.com/2014/10/01/android-and-renderscript-intrinsics/

However they are quite limited set.